# Python: A more concise syntax for variable assignment when accessing a NoneType object

Tags: python

Say, I have the following Python code

```
if obj is None:
  identifier = None
else:
  identifier = obj.id
```

where `obj` is a Python object whose class definition is not included

I barely remember there's a more concise syntax (like a one-line code?) that can achieve the same. If I wasn't dreaming, can someone please advise what that simpler syntax might be? Thanks.

Comment: No luck with search or the tutorial?

Comment: Good question in general, but I'm not sure how I'd search for this, are you?

Comment: @S.Lott - I tried to search for the answer but no luck. That's why I am posting the question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604726/x-or-y-acceptable-idiom-or-obfuscation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768175/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-provide-a-fall-back-value-in-an-assignment,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
identifier = None if obj is None else obj.id
```

Comment: Python's conditional expression to the rescue!

Comment: Just cosmetics now: `identifier = obj.id if obj else None`

Comment: @fgeller: No, this would set it to `None` if obj were, e.g., 0. `identifier = obj.id if obj is not None else None` works, but seems unnecessarily wordy.

Comment: @TomZych Well, kind of depends on what you know about obj :)

Answer (score 2):

```
identifier = getattr(obj, "id", None)
```

Comment: Note that this will use `None` whenever there isn't such an attribute on `obj`, not just when `obj is None`.

Comment: @delnan - Thanks, your comment made me realize I actually misread the question.  Tom Zych's answer is correct for what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an old python version without conditional expressions, you can resort on the evaluation semantics of boolean expressions: The value of a boolean expression is the value of that term in the expression which determines its final value. That sounds quite abstract, but in your case you can say:

```
((obj is None and [None]) or [obj.id])[0]
```

If `obj` is `None` you have

```
((True and [None]) or [obj.id])[0]
```

which is

```
([None] or [obj.id])[0]
```

As `[None]` represents a `True` value, which can be `or`ed with any expression without changing the value of the `or` expression the result is `[None][0]` which is `None`

If `obj` is not `None` you have

```
((False and [None]) or [obj.id])[0]
```

which is

```
(False or [obj.id])[0]

= ([obj.id])[0]

= obj.id
```

This is how you had to simulate the ternary operator aka "conditional if expression" if former times.

The general pattern is `a if b else c` is the same as

```
(b and [a] or [c])[0]
```