# How to initialize empty list?

Tags: python

Every time the input `s` comes from the form; the `list` is initialized again. How do I change the code to append each new `s` to the list?

Thank you.

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        s = self.request.get('sentence')
        list = []                                   
        list.append(s)                      
        htmlcode1 = HTML.table(list)
```

Comment: To change the behavior, you must change the order of your statements.  Why don't you try a few different orderings of the statements to see how the behavior changes?

Comment: Avoid names that shadow built-ins ("list").

Comment: @S.Lott: Guess and check isn't a very effective way to learn about a language. It has it's place, but I respectfully disagree in this circumstance.

Comment: @JoshD: True.  However, the question indicates such a profound lack of language skills.  Guess and Check is clearly far, far better than what was presented.

Comment: @S.Lott: That's a good advise and I've been trying new things with the code but I still could not make it work. If you take a look at the answers; you would see that there is still no answer that appends "s" to "myList". If this is so simple; may I ask your help? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel: "that there is still no answer that appends "s" to "myList".  Really?  Can you provide detailed explanations of why the answers don't work?

Comment: -1: "I've been trying new things with the code but I still could not make it work"  Delightfully vague.  Could mean anything.  Since no code was posted, it's impossible to understand what this means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the context of your code is, but this should work:

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        s = self.request.get('sentence')
        try:
            self.myList.append(s)
        except NameError:
            self.myList= [s]
        htmlcode1 = HTML.table(self.myList)
```

This makes `list` an instance variable so it'll stick around. The problem is that `list` might not exist the first time we try to use it, so in this case we need to initialize it.

Actually, looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/python-checking-variable-existing), this might be cleaner code:

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        s = self.request.get('sentence')
        if not hasattr(self, 'myList'):
            self.myList = []
        self.myList.append(s)
        htmlcode1 = HTML.table(self.myList)
```

[Edit:]
The above isn't working for some reason, so try this:

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    myList = []
    def get(self):
        s = self.request.get('sentence')
        self.myList.append(s)
        htmlcode1 = HTML.table(self.myList)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this http://codepad.org/bdCaLiUs but it still rewrites the list instead of appending.

Comment: @Zeynel you're not following instructions

Comment: @Zeynel The code you link to looks nothing like my fix. Try copying and pasting my fix into your code.

Comment: @dln385 thanks for the help. I added the exception because the way it is I get the error "htmlcode1 = HTML.table(mylist)
NameError: global name 'mylist' is not defined." (I changed "list" to "mylist" as per another commenter re: not to use variables with confusing names.

Comment: @Zeynel I'm sorry, that was my fault entirely. The last line should have `self.list`, not `list`. I updated my examples accordingly. Also, you should use [sth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001652/how-to-initialize-empty-list/4001962#4001962) if you can get it to work. His code has `self.list` three times, so make sure you got all of them when you switched to `self.myList`.

Comment: @dln385 Thanks. But still s is not appended to myList. And when I try to get what inside myList I get:     'myList': myList,
NameError: global name 'myList' is not defined

Comment: @Zeynel That error looks like you're asking for `myList` directly. `myList` is now a property of `self`, so it must be referred to as `self.myList` at all times. For example, if you want to print `myList`, you would have to use `print(self.myList)`. If I'm off the mark, could you post a larger code segment that produces that error?

Comment: @dln385 Thanks. This is what is in the list for each s: s: aaa --> myList: [u'aaa'] - s: mmmm --> myList: [u'mmmm'].

Comment: @Zeynel The fact that `self.myList` is being lost means that either you have a typo, or a new object is being created each time. In any case, I put up a third example to try. I've never used this strategy before, and I imagine it's bad code, but it just might work.

Comment: @dln385: Thanks!! This one worked. I appreciate your help. Any more commentary you may have about how this one works, for learning purposes, that's welcome too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel In the third example, I make `myList` an attribute of the __class__, not the __object__. This means that for as long as the program is run, `myList` will always remain as an attribute of the class, and you can access it from outside the class as `Test.myList`. Also, whenever you instantiate an object from the `Test` class (e.g. `testObject = Test()`), that object gets its own `myList` variable that points to the same exact data. (In other words, it's as if you had run `testObject.myList = Test.myList`.) This is why appending to `self.myList` modifies `Test.myList`.

Comment: However, `self.myList` is a different variable from `Test.myList`, so if you run `self.myList = 5`, `Test.myList` would remain unchanged. I really don't understand this well myself, but I think I should give you a few warnings. First of all, if you ever make another instance of `Test` while the program runs, that object's `myList` variable will point to the same `Test.myList`. Also, the fact that the other examples didn't work seems to show that you're creating a new object every time you want to use `get`, which is probably a bug in your code.

Comment: So what it comes down to is that I don't know whether this solution will work fine for your program, or introduce a nightmare of bugs and unexpected behavior down the road.

Answer (score 5):

You could make the list a member variable of the object and then only update it when `get()` is called:

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *p, **kw): # or whatever parameters this takes
        webapp.RequestHandler.__init__(self, *p, **kw)
        self.list = []

    def get(self):
        s = self.request.get('sentence')
        self.list.append(s)                      
        htmlcode1 = HTML.table(self.list)
```

Comment: +1 I think that creating `self.list` in `__init__` makes things more explicit

Comment: +1 This is what I wanted to do, but I gave up when I couldn't find the original `__init__()` for `webapp.RequestHandler`. I forgot about the `*p, **kw` trick.

Comment: Wait, what if `__init__` makes a call to `get`? (Again, I'm not sure what `webapp.RequestHandler` actually does). I think you should `self.list = []` before the call to `__init__`.

Comment: I tried this as is (except I changed "list" to "mylist") but it still not appending "s" to the list. "mylist" is always the same as "s". Thanks for the help.

Comment: "but it still not appending "s" to the list"?  What?  How about this?  Add `print` statements to show what's **actually** happening.  This is the correct approach.