# In Python, how do I check if a variable exists?

Tags: python, debugging, variables, object

If "x" exists, then print "x exists".

I ask this because I always get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /settings/
local variable 'avatarlink' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: To reiterate: In general, don't use `locals()`, `globals()`, don't catch `UnboundLocalError`, fix your code instead. Please, read links on scopes, namespaces, naming, and binding  in Python provided in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller-b/575337#575337

Comment: -1: If you always get this error, you have **design** issues.  You don't need to "test" for a variable, you need to fix your design.  Why are you "always" getting this error?  What design mistake are you making?

Comment: [How do i check if a variable exists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python) has a title that is almost identical to this one. Are the two questions somehow distinct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you need to know? If the code breaks because of this, it's probably because the code is wrong anyway and needs to be fixed.

That said, try checking `if 'x' in locals()` or `if 'x' in globals()`, as appropriate to where you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to quote the name (`'avatarlink' in locals()`). But the first paragraph is the real solution. +1

Comment: @delnan Of course; added quotes to reflect that.

Comment: While this is indeed the correct answer to your question, please also consider Karl's remark that your code is probably broken if you need to employ a check like this. You are currently treating the symptoms, not the cause, which is always a bad idea.

Comment: -1 You don't need the `if`. Just put the variable's name inside a `try` with and `except NameError:`. Beside being easier, you're checking for existence the way Python does, not restricting it to `locals`, 'globals`, etc.

Comment: @martineau I'm familiar with EAFP, but that seems like a pretty extreme application of the principle :)

Comment: +1: "the code is wrong anyway and needs to be fixed."

Comment: @S.Lott: The code has been fixed...but who/what are you up-voting and quoting -- some deleted comment?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Since this is something that obviously shouldn't be happening in the first place, I think using such an "extreme" application of EAFP is completely warranted. It's more *lines* of code, but does the exact same sequence of of lookups that Python normally uses for any name which is what is failing and causing the error. It would also rule-out the possibility that the `'key' in whatever` approach in the answer just looked in the wrong place.

Comment: @martineau: "who/what are you up-voting"?  This isn't a sensible question.  One upvotes an answer.  What else *could* be upvoted?  "some deleted comment"?  This isn't a sensible part of the question.  The quoted words are part of the answer.  Please clarify this comment -- it's really hard to parse.

Comment: @S.Lott: It's possible to up-vote comments as well as answers. I asked the question because I didn't see the words you quoted in the answer probably due to the way it was word-breaking in my browser -- so I didn't know what code was being referred to. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for ultimately telling me what I wanted to know.

Comment: Why should the code be wrong - you are expecting a next page cursor from a remote api, which will not be there if there isnt a next page. It is expected that it shouldnt be there when there isnt a next page. Otherwise remote api would not be JSON compliant.

Answer (score 7):

As they say in Python, "it's better to ask forgiveness than permission". So, just try and access the variable, and catch the error if it doesn't exist.

```
try:
    x
    print "x exists"
except UnboundLocalError:
    print "x doesn't exist"
```

However, I would really like to know why you think you need to do this. Usually, you would always set the variable before checking its value.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError` is a subtype of `NameError`. It would only be raised if `x` was determined at compile time to be a local variable, but hasn't yet been assigned. This can only happen inside a function, and only if there is an assignment to the name elsewhere in the function *and* there is no corresponding `global` or `nonlocal` declaration. Otherwise, a generic `NameError` will result.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
  variable
except NameError:
  print "It doesn't Exist!"
else:
  print "It exists!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check if x is in `globals()` or `locals()`.

Answer (score 1):

In python you really shouldn't be using variables which haven't been set. If need be you can set avatarLink to None.