# Python version of C#'s conditional operator (?)

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-null-coalescing-operator) but it uses the ?? operator as a null check, I want to use it as a bool true/false test.

I have this code in Python:

```
if self.trait == self.spouse.trait:
    trait = self.trait
else:
    trait = defualtTrait
```

In C# I could write this as:

```
trait = this.trait == this.spouse.trait ? this.trait : defualtTrait;
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Python?

Comment: In C# you only need the ? operator to do that.

Comment: In C# It looks like you're using the ?? operator where you could otherwise use the ? operator. Regardless, if your code works, and you understand it, I don't see any reason to deviate.  It's explicit, and clear. Sure, you could turn it into a one-liner as a few have demonstrated, but the result is effectively the same.

Comment: @WinstonEwert you are quite right. My mistake. I'll edit my question to make it helpful to other people.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can write:

```
trait = self.trait if self.trait == self.spouse.trait else defaultTrait
```

This is called a [Conditional Expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

On the null-coalescing operator in C#, what you have in the question isn't a correct usage.  That would fail at compile time.

In C#, the correct way to write what you're attempting would be this:

```
trait = this.trait == this.spouse.trait ? self.trait : defaultTrait
```

Null coalesce in C# returns the first value that isn't null in a chain of values (or null if there are no non-null values).  For example, what you'd write in C# to return the first non-null trait or a default trait if all the others were null is actually this:

```
trait = this.spouse.trait ?? self.trait ?? defaultTrait;
```

Comment: Right, I was thinking the ?: conditional operator and wrote out the ?? null-coalescing operator. My bad.