# Assignment with "or" in python

Tags: python, coding-style, variable-assignment

Is it considered bad style to assign values to variables like this?

```
x = "foobar" or None
y = some_variable or None
```

In the above example, x gets the value 'foobar'.

Comment: I don't see any function being called just truth testing. Where are the side effects?

Comment: That's not what a "side effect" is.

Comment: @jcollado: I am not assigning a boolean to x and y. The value that gets assigned is the first short-circuited item that is True. The first case being "foobar", and the latter depends on the boolean value of some_variable.

Comment: @Ramin I know you're not assigning a boolean. My point is that I don't see any [side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: @jcollado, what would you call the behavior of the `or` operator where a boolean result is expected, but conveniently the first true value is returned?

Comment: @Ramin: "A somewhat unusual behavior", "side effect" has a very different meaning in computer science. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Comment: C++ be damned for all the confusion! Or was C the first language to use the ++ operator? Does python even have side-effects?

Comment: Yes Python has them, terrible, dark, dangerous (a Haskeller)

Comment: Related: [What does an 'x = y or z' assignment do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21566106/3357935)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, it's a common practice. It's only considered bad style for expressions that are considerably longer than yours.

Comment: It is considered an anti-pattern in JavaScript.
It does not read naturally to uninitiated and you cannot assign falsy values.

Comment: @diginoise Nothing in Javascript or any other language reads naturally to the sufficiently uninitiated. But once a developer is familiar with short-cut evaluation (as used in, e.g., `if foo or bar...`, which is quite a common idiom in JS, Python and many other languages) it reads just as naturally, though you may have to think about it for a moment the very first time you see it.
However, "falsy" values are a problem in Python, too, as with 'list = []; return list or False`

Answer (score 32):

The primary danger of doing something like this is the possibility that (in the second case) `some_variable` is False but not None (the integer `0`, for instance) and you don't want to end up with `y` equal to None in that case.

Answer (score 9):

I also feel a bit unconfortable using that kind of expressions. In Learning Python 4ed it is called a "somewhat unusual behavior". 
Later Mark Lutz says:

> ...it turns out to be a fairly common coding paradigm in Python: to
>   select a nonempty object from among a fixed-size set, simply string
>   them together in an or expression. In simpler form, this is also
>   commonly used to designate a default...

In fact, they produce concise one-line expressions that help to eliminate line noise from the code.
This behavior is the basis for a form of the if/else ternary operator:

```
A = Y if X else Z
```

Comment: But it may cause to repeat a long parameters where `Y = X`. For instance: `A = my_main_dictionary.my_sub_dictionary.my_value if my_main_dictionary.my_sub_dictionary.my_value else None` or `A = my_main_dictionary.my_sub_dictionary.my_value or None`

Comment: @RoeeGavirel just assign `my_value` to a local variable

Answer (score 9):

OP's syntax is perfectly fine. 
The official name for "assignment with or" is *null coalescing* and there's actually a Wikipedia page about it now! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator 
This question may be useful as well:
[Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator)