# What does an 'x = y or z' assignment do in Python?

Tags: python, boolean, variable-assignment

## Why do we see Python assignments with `or`?

For example:

```
def my_function(arg_1=None, arg_2=0):
    determination = arg_1 or arg_2 or 'no arguments given!'
    print(determination)
    return determination
```

When called with no arguments, the above function would print and return `'no arguments given!'`

Why does Python do this, and how can one best make best use of this functionality?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## What the "`or`" expression does on assignment:

We sometimes see examples of this in Python as a substitute for conditional expression with ternary assignments, (in fact, [it helped inspire the language to add conditional statements](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)).

```
x = a or b
```

If `bool(a)` returns `False`, then `x` is assigned the value of `b`

### Identical Use-case of Conditional Expressions (i.e. Ternary Assignments)

Here's an example of such a conditional expression that accomplishes the same thing, but with perhaps a bit less mystery.

```
def my_function(arg_1=None, arg_2=0):
    determination = arg_1 if arg_1 else arg_2 if arg_2 else 'no arguments given!'
    print(determination)
    return determination
```

Repeating this syntax too much is considered to be bad style, otherwise [it's OK for one-liners.](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Conditional_Expressions) The downside is that it *is* a bit repetitive.

### `or` Expressions

The base case, `x or y` returns `x` if `bool(x)` evaluates `True`, else it evaluates `y`, ([see the docs for reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)). Therefore, a series of `or` expressions has the effect of returning the first item that evaluates `True`, or the last item.

For example

```
'' or [] or 'apple' or () or set(['banana'])
```

returns `'apple'`, the first item that evaluates as `True`, and

```
'' or [] or ()
```

returns `()`, even though it evaluates as `False`.

#### Extended `and` usage

For contrast, `x and y` returns `x` if `bool(x)` evaluates as `False`, else it returns `y`.

It makes sense that `and` would work this way when you consider that all of the conditions in a conditional `and` series needs to evaluate as `True` for the control flow to proceed down that path, and that it makes no sense to continue evaluating those items when you come across one that is `False`.

The utility of using `and` for assignment is not immediately as apparent as using `or`, but it was historically used for ternary assignment. That is, before this more clear and straightforward construction was available:

```
a = x if condition else y
```

the equivalent formed with boolean operators was:

```
a = condition and x or z                      # don't do this!
```

which while the meaning is derivable based on a full understanding of Python `and` and `or` evaluation, is not nearly as readable as the ternary conditional, and is best avoided altogether.

## Conclusion

**Using Boolean expressions for assignment must be done carefully.** Definitely never use `and` for assignment, which is confusing enough to be quite error-prone. Style mavens will find use of `or` for assignments less preferable (than the more verbose ternary, `if` condition `else`), but I have found that it is so common in the professional Python community that it could be considered idiomatic.

If you choose to use it, do so cautiously with the understanding that the final element, if reached, will always be returned regardless of its evaluation, so that final element should probably be a *literal*, so that you know you have a good default fallback for your variable.

Comment: Great answer! I would like to argue that you shouldn't say whether something evaluates to `True` or `False`, but rather, if it is truthy. `b = 1 or 2` means `b == 1`, but neither are `True`. Maybe I'm just being pedantic, or even confused?

Comment: Apparently, I wasn't clear enough. :) `b = 1 or 2` means that it first evaluates the item before the `or`, and returns it if it evaluates as `True` (in a boolean context). I'll clarify in the text ASAP. Meanwhile, check out the documentation on this: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations look for the text that starts with "The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, "...

Comment: Oh yeah, I know all that. I'm just being persnickety about types.

Comment: The two examples for using `and` don't seem to be fully equivalent. Consider `x = False; y = "good"; condition = True`. Then `x if condition else y` gives `x` (False) but `condition and x or y` gives `y` ("good"). So it's definitely good that the inline-if exists.