# Purpose of square brackets when doing aggregate, sum and filter

Tags: python, django, filter, sum, aggregate

In the below I am trying to understand the purpose of `['total__sum'] or 0`. I have tried to Google it but I am not entirely sure what to Google. Can anyone provide a simple explanation or point me the in the direction of some relevant documentation?

```
new_qs = qs.filter(updated__day=new_time.day, updated__month=new_time.month)
day_total = new_qs.totals_data()['total__sum'] or 0

def totals_data(self):
return self.aggregate(Sum("cart__total"),Avg("cart__total"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**new_qs.totals_data()['total__sum'] or 0** means that, if *bool* value of `new_qs.totals_data()['total__sum']` is **False**, then assignment of 0 will happen.

Further expanding, `day_total = new_qs.totals_data()['total__sum'] or 0`  day will be `0` when `bool(new_qs.totals_data()['total__sum'])` returns **False** else, the current value will be assigned.

So, when will **bool(new_qs.totals_data()['total__sum'])** will return **False**? When the value is `None` or `empty object`.

You can see further about this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566107/10860596) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Answer (score 1):

`new_qs.totals_data()` is a dictionary that you access by giving the key in square brackets.

I added one line to your code for clarification below:

```
new_qs = qs.filter(updated__day=new_time.day, updated__month=new_time.month)
dictionary_with_totals = new_qs.totals_data()
day_total = dictionary_with_totals['total__sum'] or 0
```