# What does something = other_thing or antother_thing?

Tags: python

I was reading the module subprocess and I reach the following line of code:

```
self.lpAttributeList = lpAttributeList or {"handle_list": []}
```

Does anyone know what the expression `x = y or z` mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this question-answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566106/what-does-an-x-y-or-z-assignment-do-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does an 'x = y or z' assignment do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566106/what-does-an-x-y-or-z-assignment-do-in-python)

Comment: `y or z` is just a regular boolean expression in Python