# What does the "or" operator mean in Python's "return statement"?

Tags: python

I read the following lines of code:

```py
    def removeKdigits(num,k):
        selected_digits=[]
        for digit in num:
            while k and selected_digits and selected_digits[-1]> digit:
                 selected_digits.pop()
                 k-=1
            selected_digits.append(digit)
        num_digits=len(num)-k
        return "".join(stack[: num_digits]).lstrip("0") or "0"
```

I kind of understand what the last return statement means: use "0" as a default return value, but how does this work exactly in python ?

Comment: The argument to `return` is an expression, so your question really resolves to what `or` means in an expression (which should be fairly straightforward to figure out; but maybe read up on Python's concept of "truthy" vs "falsey" values).

Answer (score 0):

```py
return a or b
```

If a is true return it,
If b is true return it,
If a and b are false return b.

`return` is actually not important here, consider the following example:

```
>>> result = '' or 'whatever' 
>>> print(result) 
'whatever' 
>>> result = False or 'whatever' 
>>> print(result) 
'whatever'
```

So the behavior of `or` operator in `return` statement is the same as in value assignment. cf [What does an 'x = y or z' assignment do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21566106/12234753)

source: https://qr.ae/pvFOLh