# How to avoid repetition in a ternary operator assignment?

Tags: python

When fetching a number of config values from `os.environ`, it's nice to have defaults in the python code to easily allow the application to start in a number of contexts.
A typical django settings.py has a number of

```
SOME_SETTING = os.environ.get('SOME_SETTING')
```

lines.

To provide sensible defaults we opted for

```
SOME_SETTING = os.environ.get('SOME_SETTING') or "theValue"
```

However, this [is error prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747740/assignment-with-or-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) because calling the application with

```
SOME_SETTING=""
```

manage.py

will lead `SOME_SETTING` to be set to `theValue` instead of the explicitly defined `""`

Is there a way to assign values in python using the ternary `a = b if b else d` without repeating `b` or assigning it to a shorthand variable before?

this becomes obvious if we look at

```
SOME_VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME = os.environ.get('SOME_VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME') if os.environ.get('SOME_VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME') else 'meh'
```

It would be much nicer to be able to do something like

```
SOME_VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME = if os.environ.get('SOME_VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME') else 'meh'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like Python's built-in mapping class `dict`, `os.environ.get` has a second argument, and it seems like you want it:

```
SOME_SETTING = os.environ.get('SOME_SETTING', "theValue")
```

This is the same as

```
try:
    SOME_SETTING = os.environ['SOME_SETTING']
except KeyError:
    SOME_SETTING = "theValue"
```

Comment: Beat me by a couple seconds <g> - but you should edit your post to mention that the `default` argument is not specific to `os.environ.get`, it's for just any dict or dict-like (mapping) types.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

If you read `dict.get()`'s doc, you'll find out the method's signature is `get(self, key, default=None)`. The `default` argument is what gets returned if the key is not found in the dict (and default to a sensible `None`). So you can use this second argument instead of doing an erroneous boolean test:

```
SOME_SETTING = os.environ.get('SOME_SETTING', "theValue")
```

Comment: Trivia: `os.environ` is *not* a dict, though it behaves almost identically.

Comment: Indeed - but it's documented as a "dict-like", which means it supports the same API as a dict ;-)