# How does "var = var or str.lower" become callable?

Tags: python

I am having difficulties understanding the following block of Python code:

```
>>> before = None
>>> before = before or str.lower
>>> t = before("Some Text")
>>> t
'some text'
```

It seems that `before` is a callable function here (in particular, `callable(before)` returns `True`) but I don't understand how this works. Can someone clearly explain the underlying logic? When I read the above block of code, my first though was that `before` was a ordinary variable. Also, I am wondering if this is considered good coding practice as it's the first time I encounter this particular syntax?

Comment: `None` is false, so `before` becomes `str.lower`.

Comment: No it's not good coding practice. That is poorly written code and should be avoided.

Comment: @Mad Add to duplicates list please: [What does an 'x = y or z' assignment do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21566106/4518341)

Comment: Related: [Assignment with “or” in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8747740/4518341)

Comment: What you are looking at is an antipattern for `str.lower if before is None else before`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710631/is-there-shorthand-for-returning-a-default-value-if-none-in-python/13710674

Comment: Conditional expressions were intended to replace the broken practice of using `a and b or c` as a ternary operator. You have bigger design issues regarding how `before` is initialized and/or set if `before = before or str.lower` can behave differently than `before = str.lower if before is None else before`.