# Is there shorthand for returning a default value if None in Python?

Tags: python

In C#, I can say `x ?? ""`, which will give me x if x is not null, and the empty string if x is null. I've found it useful for working with databases.

Is there a way to return a default value if Python finds None in a variable?

Comment: I'm used to Ruby's `||=` operator which is great for caching variables. In my case the variable was not defined so `a or b` did not work for me. I found the following works though if you need variable caching which comes in handy with Jupyter Notebooks: `a = a if 'a' in locals() else do_work()`. This is great if you want to create a backup variable and make sure you don't overwrite it as you're running different cells if you accidentally run the same cell again.

Answer (score 568, accepted):

You could use the `or` operator:

```
return x or "default"
```

Note that this also returns `"default"` if `x` is any falsy value, including an empty list, 0, empty string, or even `datetime.time(0)` (midnight).

Comment: This will return "default" if x is any falsy value, e.g. `None`, `[]`, `""`, etc. but is often good enough and cleaner looking.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: Would return "default" if x is 0 (zero) as well

Comment: I consider this to be a bad practice - this uses some conversion to bool of 'x' and this will fail if no such conversion found (for instance, pandas DataFrames and numpy arrays)

Comment: ``x or default`` is an **antipattern**! It is a frequent source of errors that are hard to debug, because for many subtle reasons x could evaluate to false even if it is the desired value.

Comment: I agree with QuantMetropolis and Alleo. Very bad practice. If there's a need for a default value, then it's because you know that x can appear with some irregular value (or type) which you want to replace. So your code should detect that specific circumstance. Not only does this avoid surprise side effects (like providing the default when x has legitimate value zero), but it also documents for maintenance programmers (possibly your later self) what you intended to happen here.

Comment: **WARNING: AntiPattern** : use `return "default" if x is None else x`

Comment: ^ I was receiving a lot of up votes on my unselected answer below, so assumed people were discovering this anti-pattern the hard way.  Hopefully the above comment will grab people's attention and save some heartache.

Comment: Because of duck-typing, many use-cases actually require a comparison to any false-y value; which polymorphic functions are treating/returning as a None == NULL == '' == 0 value. Stop trying to shoehorn Javascript or .NET principles onto python. Take the default value, and use EAFP later on.

Comment: So `time.now() == False` once a day. That's just great.

Comment: It's perfectly valid and not an antipattern. Just as with everything else, you need to know what it does: it doesn't just ignore None, but all "falsy" values, including 0, "", [] and {} (and some more special cases, like instances which override their evaluation). If that's what you want (and in lots of cases it is), it's perfect.

Comment: @Hejazzman "It is a frequent source of errors that are hard to debug, because for many subtle reasons x could evaluate to false even if it is the desired value."

Comment: @Hejazzman It may be frequently what people want, but the question explicitly asked for a null test, not a falsy test. 0 may be a desirable value in a lot of cases also, can't assume that the asker doesn't care about other falsy values being ignored, and MrR is correct, things like this get hard to debug, particularly if they come up rarely. I had something in a production server for months before someone hit the edge case that broke everything.

Comment: Also, this would fail to return a valid value, if you're returning a function call and it raises an exception.

Comment: This will return a default value for many cases other than just `None`, it's not even close to being a correct answer, yet is so upvoted.

Comment: @Hejazzman its working just fine for me too. I used it to test if a cell in a spreadsheet was empty. I'm only expecting a string so im happy to get the default if whatever is in the cell evaluated to False. Definitely valid for some specific cases of course you run into issues if you use anything carelessly

Comment: Let's dispel the myth that this is bad practice, by invoking PEP-8: "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false"

Answer (score 248):

```
return "default" if x is None else x
```

try the above.

Comment: Use this when you only want the default value when x is None and not other false values.  Which matches the C# x??"default"

Comment: Otherwise, just drop the `is None`, and let `x` evaluate as a Boolean value on its own.

Comment: Or use @starhusker's x or "default".  Often I used to use the ternary sytax b/c I what to do x.value if X might be None.  So x.value if x else "default",  but this is more readable  getattr(obj, "value", "default"). The trade off is that the later is not caught by many auto-refactor tools.

Comment: Its Pythonic #PEP20 The Zen of Python
Explicit is better than implicit. Better to handle only for None Cases if thats what it takes.

Comment: This is also how it is implemented in the convenience function `ifnone` from the `fastai` library. So if you are using that library, then that is your shorthand.

Comment: meh... it's ok, but not as good as c#, because you need to create a variable for x.  In c# for instance x can be a function call, such as `return foo() ?? "default"`. But in python you'll need `x = foo(); return x if x is not None else "default"`.  Not as pretty.

Answer (score 72):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
x if x is not None else some_value
```

Example:

```
In [22]: x = None

In [23]: print x if x is not None else "foo"
foo

In [24]: x = "bar"

In [25]: print x if x is not None else "foo"
bar
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got the ternary syntax `x if x else ''` - is that what you're after?

Comment: And it's not actually *called* a ternary syntax (any operator that takes 3 operands could be called a ternary operator, not just this one). It's proper name is a conditional expression.

Comment: doesn't work for if x==0 or any falsy value

Comment: @wisbucky then you make the criteria specific to what context is necessary... `None` or any other sentinel value or criteria...

Comment: @JonClements The criteria is explicit in the original question; therefore, your solution is buggy.