# or & and in if statement in one line not working as supposed

Tags: python-3.x

I am not sure why this code is not working as supposed, can any one help me please ?

```
# check if a user eligible for watching coco movie or not.
# if user name starts with "a" or "A" and his age is greater then 10 then he can, else not.

user_name = input("please enter your name in letters here: ")
user_age = int(input("please enter your age in whole numbers here: "))

if user_name[0] == ("a" or "A") and user_age > 10 :
  print("you can watch coco movie")
else:
  print("sorry, you cannot watch coco")
```

I tested this code with every possible condition and it is working fine but with last condition is not working as supposed , in last condition don't know why condition is False.

I am pasting here all tested conditions and there results from IDLE :

```
please enter your name in letters here: a
please enter your age in whole numbers here: 9
sorry, you cannot watch coco
>>> 
====================== RESTART: D:\MyPythonScripts\1.py ======================
please enter your name in letters here: a
please enter your age in whole numbers here: 10
sorry, you cannot watch coco
>>> 
====================== RESTART: D:\MyPythonScripts\1.py ======================
please enter your name in letters here: a
please enter your age in whole numbers here: 11
you can watch coco movie
>>> 
====================== RESTART: D:\MyPythonScripts\1.py ======================
please enter your name in letters here: A
please enter your age in whole numbers here: 9
sorry, you cannot watch coco
>>> 
====================== RESTART: D:\MyPythonScripts\1.py ======================
please enter your name in letters here: A
please enter your age in whole numbers here: 10
sorry, you cannot watch coco
>>> 
====================== RESTART: D:\MyPythonScripts\1.py ======================
please enter your name in letters here: A
please enter your age in whole numbers here: 11
sorry, you cannot watch coco
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: @ Patrick Haugh. sorry sir my question is different.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you wrote, user_name[0] is compared to the expression ('a' or 'A').  The expression ('a' or 'A') evaluates to 'a'.  Try this,

`print( 'a' or 'A' )`

The result is

`a`

Therefore, the condition tests true only when user_name begins with 'a' and age is greater than 10.

Here is a code snippet that does what you perhaps intended:

```
if user_name[0] in 'aA' and user_age > 10 :
  print("you can watch coco movie")
else:
  print("sorry, you cannot watch coco")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your last test case wasn't getting the expected value was this condition

```
user_name[0] == ("a" or "A")
```

You see ("a" or "A") is being evaluated differently than you think. The parenthesis make this it's own expression. 
That expression basically says **If 'a' is null then return 'A'**

This always returns 'a' therefore, returning that output.

```
user_name[0] == "a" or user_name[0] == "A"
```

Should fix this

Look into this post for greater explaination
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710667/9310329

Cheers

Comment: To avoid indexing twice: `user_name[0] in ('a', 'A')`

Comment: @ Brad Solomon. Thank you very much sir , now i understand what mistake was i making and also the alternate ways to achieve this goal.
one more question sir. What if i change the condition from "('a' or 'A')" to " 'a' or 'A' " ?

Comment: @BradSolomon To avoid tuple construction: `user_name[0] in 'aA'`.