# Add/sum two lists or tuples of uneven length

Tags: python, list, sum, tuples, addition

In Python, is there a good way to add/sum (or otherwise combine) two lists of uneven length?

e.g. given some lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

produce list `c`:

```
c = [2,4,6,4]
```

where each element is the sum of `a` and `b`, taking a missing element as zero?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]
[2, 4, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is why self-answers are still useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I landed up using:

```
[ (ax or 0) + (bx or 0) for (ax, bx) in map(None, a, b) ]
```

where [`n or 0` is used to coalesce `None` to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978745/398670), and [`map(None, a, b)` is used as a null-expanding version of `zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277311/398670).

Problems? Better answers?

Comment: Just note that the `map(None)` trick only works in Python 2.x; for 3.x, you should use `itertools.zip_longest` as in @ZeroPiraeus's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3]
In [2]: b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [3]: [i+ii if i and ii else i or ii for (i,ii) in map(lambda x,y: (x,y),a,b)]
Out[3]: [2, 4, 6, 4]
```