# Better way of filtering in Django and seeing if the object exists

Tags: python, django

A lot of times I find myself filtering for an object and returning `None` if it can't be found. However, the method I do this seems really inefficient (in terms of lines of code)

When I filter for an object I normally do something like this:

```
person = Person.objects.filter(id=id)
if person:
    person = Person.objects.get(id=id)
else:
    person = None
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

**Edit**
I have made edits to clarify confusion on my end. 
The filter query should always return 1 object, if it exists.

Comment: Or maybe a coalescing operator `person = Person.objects.filter(name=name) or None`? This should default to `person = None` if `Person.objects.filter(name=name)` is falsy

Comment: I don't understand why you repeat the filter in the if statement.

Comment: Made an update to clarify confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.get()` if you want to get one person or return None.

```
try:
    person = Person.objects.get(name=name)
except (Person.DoesNotExist, Person.MultipleObjectsReturned) as e:
    person = None
```

Comment: it is really bad idea, because Exception will be raised even if it will be some problem with db (connection, etc.). And the person could easily be there, but you return None.

Comment: I see, I'll fix it.

Comment: Is there a one line solution for this? It sees like this is a bit of code for something that is a common query.

Comment: Not to sure about a 1 line solution, but using `try except` follows python style guidelines over `if/else` format. https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do like this.

```
person = Person.objects.get(name=name)
```

will raise an exception.

What you can do is:

```
try:
   person = Person.objects.get(name=name)
except Person.MultipleObjectsReturned:
   person = Person.objects.first()
except Person.DoesNotExist:
   person = None
```

But Best thing here is to use:

```
some_queryset.filter(pk=entry.pk).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if/else` is unusual in that you assign `person` twice. I can't understand why. You have two options I think.

First, you could reduce `if/else` to just `if` like this:

```
person = Person.objects.filter(name=name)
if not person:
    person = None
```

Or with a [coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator) to make it very terse:

```
person = Person.objects.filter(name=name) or None
```

Which will return `person = None` if `Person.objects.filter(name=name)` is falsy.

Comment: This would work great if I could use `.get` and the query didn't crash when None is expected to be returned.

Comment: @JohnSmith the edit to your question has made it entirely different. Originally you repeated the `filter` in `if/else` so my 1-liner is exactly the same as what you were doing originally. Now it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Filter return list (or empty list), so if you know you get list, and want to replace empty list with None:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(name=name)
if not any(person):
    person = None
# single person
person = persons[0] # but there could be more than one
```

If you want single Person

```
try:
   person = Person.objects.get(name=name)
except Person.MultipleObjectsReturned:
   # do something if there is more Persons with that name
   person = Person.objects.first() # for example return first person with that name
except Person.DoesNotExist:
   person = None # set person None
```

Comment: Why would you need `any()` here? It's an empty list, which is falsy. `if not person`?

Comment: if it is not empty it will iter full list -> so it will be slower if there is more than one person, **any** function return True if there is person[0] or False if ther is no person[0]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `[]` will always return false, and nothing has to be iterated because the list is simply empty. A list with items in it will return `True`, but it shouldn't have to iterate the entire list to do the check, surely?

Comment: But it's a list. An empty list is itself, by default, considered `False` in Python. `print bool([])`. It doesn't matter about the nature of its contents; if it's empty, it's false.

Comment: I'm not arguing this for the sake of it btw. I don't think I've seen `any()` used in this scenario and since you're suggesting that it causes it to only check the first element of the list rather than iterate the entire list to return `True`, I have some investigation to do :)

Comment: the result is same, but any is little bit faster:

Comment: try create for example 999999 persons and in ipython run:
`%timeit if any(Person.objects.all()): x=1`
and
`%timeit if Person.objects.all(): x=1`
and the second one will be little bit slower. So yes maybe in this example it does not matter, but I usually use 'any' for checking collections.

Comment: Missed your comment as I was setting up my own test case, which I have run on loops lasting ~5 secs each. No distinguishable difference between them on `100000` list content checks, each containing 1000 items. Since it's calling a built-in on each iteration but causing no obvious overhead I will accept that there could be situations that this might be faster (or maybe `if not` does this under the hood anyway). Not related to question, but +1 for identifying this for me and teaching me something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists()`

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

> If you only want to determine if at least one result exists (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s more efficient to use exists().

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=123)
if some_queryset.filter(pk=entry.pk).exists():
    print("Entry contained in queryset")
else:
   return None
```

You can shorten this a little if lines of code is a concern. However:

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you
>   know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists()
>   will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an
>   extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using
>   bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if
>   any were returned.

Comment: I'm going by the title of your question with this answer - how do I tell if an object *exists*.