# How to design control flow for a "sifter" like behavior in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, coding-style

Say there's a kind of function that returns either some value or `None`, and we have three such functions: `egg`, `ham` and `spam`.

The goal is to call `egg`, `ham`, `spam` and return the first non-None value returned, and if there's no valid value return, return `None`.

The most straightforward way would be:

```
def func():
    ret = egg()
    if ret:
        return ret
    ret = ham()
    if ret:
        return ret
    ret = spam()
    if ret:
        return ret
    return None
```

or, a smarter but maybe harder to read solution is:

```
def func():
    return egg() or ham() or spam()
```

Here're my questions (there could be more than three candidate functions to call):

1. Is the second way hard to read and should be avoided?
2. Is there a better way to design such control flow? I remember there's something in Lisp that does exactly this, but what about in Python?

Comment: The second one actually is far more readable, in my view.

Comment: @sytech I agree if it is a handful, 2-3 ideally. Much more than that and the only reasonable thing to do is to write a function for it.

Comment: If you want a really unreadable solution, how about `next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: not x, (f() for f in [egg, ham, spam])))` Although that may be favorable if you have a large set of functions.

Comment: @sytech I thought about using `next` + generator with if, but I couldn't avoid evaluating the valid return value twice. Didn't know dropwhile even exists XD

Comment: @Uduse you can do something like `next(r for f in (eggs, ham, spam) for r in (f(),) if r)` but it's hardly elegant. And really, you should be doing `next((r for f in (eggs, ham, spam) for r in (f(),) if r), None)` to be safe

Comment: 0 and False would fail and are not None.  So strictly speaking you wouldn't necessarily return the first non-None value with either of those.  The first "truthy" value, but not the first non-None.  But if that's what you're after, then I don't think most people would find the second hard to read.  You could look at an example of a coalesce function at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator for a check for None

Answer (score 0):

As this requirement is very similar to the builtin `any()` I would write:

```
def anyval(iterable):
    r = None
    for r in iterable:
        if callable(r):
            r = r()
        if r != None:
            break
    return r


def foo():
    return None

def bar():
    return 0

def baz(x):
    return x * 3.14

print(anyval([None,foo,bar]))
print(anyval([None,lambda: baz(3.14)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def sifter():
  funcs = [eggs, ham, spam]
  result = None
  while funcs and result is None:
    result = funcs.pop(0)()
  return result
```

A little explanation:
assuming, as in the question, that all the functions to run accept no arguments the `while funcs and result is None` bit ensures there are more functions to try and that the current result is still None.
in the while loop we:

1. Pop the first item from the list of funcs `funcs.pop(0)`. (The list of funcs then looses that func)
2. call the poped function `()`
3. Assign what is returned from the function call to the name `result =`

Ready for the next loop through the while statement.

Comment: How's the explanation @Uduse?

Comment: it's hard to track the flow of `result` in a skim. When I say "really hard to read" I mean it's hard to grasp what's going on in 5 seconds. However, in terms of succinctness, I think you're doing a great job.

Comment: Hi @Uduse, I didn't try to be too compact, An intermediate programmer should be able to grasp this, but it does do a pop, a function call, and an assignment in one statement. You could introduce a tmp variable to take the popped function, then call the tmp function and assign to result in another separate line if it is too complex for your needs.