# Why var or var2 in test don't work in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not actually able to understand why `var or var2 in test` is always True.

My code looks like:

```
if 'test' or 'test1' in somevar:
    print('hue')
```

It always return TRUE
Thanks

Comment: Python reads it like this: `('test') or ('test1' in somevar)`. Since `'test'` is true, it will always be true.

Comment: Have you looked at what `'test' or 'test1' in somevar` actually evaluates to?  `print('test' or 'test1' in somevar)` See [Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator) for an explanation.

Comment: @Loocid why it  does that?

Comment: @attackernine https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence `or` is ranked lower than `in` so `in` expressions are evaluated first.