# Ignore IndexError in python (Something like null coalescing operator on list subscription)

Tags: python, index-error, null-coalescing-operator

Is there a pythonic way to make python ignore `IndexError` and just return a default value or `None` when I access a list/array with an out-of-range index?

```
import sys
input = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]
```

This may cause `IndexError` when the program is run with no more than 2 parameters. However if I want to say that there are default values for `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, then I should write like:

```
import sys
input = len(sys.argv) > 1 ? sys.argv[1] : DefaultValue1
output = len(sys.argv) > 2 ? sys.argv[2] : DefaultValue2
```

Is there any pythonic way to shorten this statements exept `try`?

(like `name = input or "Not set"` for pythonic null-colaescing operator)

[Related post? (using `or` operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module?

Comment: or how about making a `dict` from `sys.argv` list and using `dict.get` method?

Comment: A more high-level alternative to argparse would be [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/).

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thank you for introducing me that wonderful module! But what should I do if I want to solve this problem without argparse? Should I create a dictionary for the lists?

Comment: @KlausD. I am surprised that there are something like annotations in python too.

Comment: There are annotations, but they are something else. These are decorators, which can modify a class, method or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure whether this is really pythonic, but you could extend `sys.argv` with an array containing `None` and slice it. Then you just have to test the values against `None`:

```
input, output = (sys.argv + [None] * 2)[:2]
if input is None: input = defaultValue1
if output is None: output = defaultValue2
```

Or in a one liner:

```
defaultValues = [defaultValue1, defaultValue2]
input, output = (val if val is not None else defaultValues[i]
                 for i, val in enumerate((sys.argv + [None] * 2)[:2]))
```

Close to a matter of taste...

Comment: And that may be used in other applications? :)

Comment: For a serious application, `argparse` or any other true command line parsing tool will be a must. You asked for a possible short implementation, I just proposed one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set your deafult values in `default_val_a` and `default_val_b` and set your index in `index` a is your `sys.arg[1]` and b is your `sys.arg[2]`. This is the most pythonic and single line way that i can come up:

```
import sys

a = [1]
b = []

default_val_a = [1, 2, 3]
default_val_b = [4, 5, 6]

index = 1

a = default_val_a[index] if len(a) <= index or not a else a[index]
b = default_val_b[index] if len(b) <= index or not b else b[index]

print(a, b)
```

And the structure is like that:

```
VAR = DEFAULT_VALUE[INDEX] if len(VAR) <= INDEX or not VAR else VAR[INDEX]
```

Comment: I am not worried about `TypeError`, but I' worried about `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `IndexError`.