# SQL COALESCE() method in python

Tags: python, sql

How could I recreate the COALESCE() method from SQL, but in python?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator) may answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `or`, in which your expression will be equal to the first logical `True`:

```
var = 1
res = var or 2 # res=1

var = None
res = var or 1 # res=1
```

Comment: This will not manage correctly other "logical False" values (like 0 or "")

Answer (score 4):

COALESCE is a variadic function, so you need a little more than just Python's `or`:

```
def coalesce(iterable):
    for el in iterable:
        if el is not None:
            return el
    return None
```

This assumes that Python's `None` is the equivalent of SQL's NULL.

More compactly, you could adapt the `first_true()` "recipe" from the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def coalesce(iterable):
    return next((el for el in iterable if el is not None), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to limit yourself to an iterable itself, but a flexible list of args, you can use this:

```py
def coalesce(*args):
  for el in args:
    if el is not None:
      return el
  return None
```

or use this one which is even more flexible

```py
def coalesce(*args, preds=[False, None]):
  for el in args:
    if el not in preds:
      return el
  return None
```