# how to assign an alternate value to a variable if it is none

Tags: python, optimization

I am just wondering if there is a way to assign a value/alternate value when it is `None` as below

conventional way

```
result = a if a else b
```

Expected way

```
result = assign(a,b)
```

PS: I could create a custom function but I would like to know if there is something by default already

Comment: what is wrong with res = a_default if a is None else set_a?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    a = None
    b = "Hi"
    result = a or b
    print(result) # prints "Hi"

    a = "Hello"
    b = "Hi"
    result = a or b
    print(result) # prints "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
result = a or b
```

If `a` is none, `result` will be `b`