# add function to a dict class WITHOUT OVERRIDING IT

Tags: python

is there any way to add functionality to dict itself?   IE - I do not want to override it - I want to create essential an extension method or mixin.

There are a log of reasons I would like to do this - but for instance - I'd like to do something like

```py
def safe_get( the_dictionary, key ):
    return None if the_dictionary is None else the_dictionary.get(key)

# this does NOT work, because dict is a built in type
dict.safe_get = safe_get
```

because this is tolerable:

```py
   result = event.safe_get("request_context").safe_get("identity").safe_get("sourceIp")
```

and this is ridiculous:

```py
   result = safe_get( safe_get( safe_get( event, 'request_context'), 'identity'), 'sourceIp')
```

or is there another (shorter == better) way of doing the same thing?

When I google I see people defining their own classes and things - but I don't create "event" - it comes from amazon, so I have no control over it, and can't change it to another type. I could wrap it - but that would be even more code :(

Comment: No, you can't modify built-ins. A wrapper class is not the worst idea.

Comment: btw, `event` usually comes as a plain dict in aws, so you could easily wrap it in a custom dict class or else use something like a dot dict access, which should be safe for nested traversal. I.e `event.context.identity.[0].source_ip`.

Comment: yeah - I know - that's what I mentioend - the question is really about - is there any way to get around that restriction - for instance in many languages they have like "monkey patching" or other such hacks.... so I'm just wondering if there's any way I can _achieve_ the same result, knowing the restrictions in place...

Comment: You can monkey-patch in Python, but not built-ins. Their implementation may not even be Python (`dict` is [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c) for CPython, for example).

Comment: Even if you could do this, it wouldn't allow your `safe_get` to work. `self` can never be `None`, because that isn't a dictionary.

Comment: By the way: A method which None-checks the object it is bound to doesn't make sense. If the object is None, the method call would fail with an exception anyway.

Comment: @Barmar You could have also monkey-patched `NoneType` if it was possible.

Comment: Good point. So you also need `NoneType.safe_get = safe_get`.

Comment: @Selcuk True, but it doesn't seem to matter. Similar to `dict.get("key", default)` -- you can't tell if you got the default because the key was missing or that was its value.

Comment: @Barmar True, that's why I deleted that comment. It kind of matters if you have a `safe_get` implementation for another built-in that returns something other than `None` for `None`, though.

Comment: Related: [Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407132/) so you could do `.get()?.get()?.get()` and each method is only called if the result of the previous one is not null. (short answer: no, but [PEP505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/#pep-deferral) is about it).

Comment: can you override "."?    like java's proxy object or similar?    I thought about making a Safe  class with a __getitem__  - which sort of works, but it leaves you with the wrong type at the end - eg  result = Safe( event )["request_context"]["identity"]["sourceIp"] is tolerable, but leaves you holding a Safe object, not a string.   If I can make a pure object proxy I could do Safe(event).request_context.identity.sourceIp

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - yeah been through that thing - I actually spend a lot more time in C#, and I'm very used to x?.y?.z?.w - which is why not having it so painful in other languages!

Answer (score 2):

The question as-is can't really be answered, but there are two alternative solutions I'd propose:

```
def safe_get(d, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        d = d.get(key)
        if d is None:
            return None
    return d

result = safe_get(event, "request_context", "identity", "sourceIp")
```

Or:

```
class NamespaceWrapper:
    def __init__(self, wrapped: dict):
        self._wrapped = wrapped
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if self._wrapped is None:
            return self
        return NamespaceWrapper(self, self._wrapped.get(attr))
    def unwrap(self):
        return self._wrapped

result = NamespaceWrapper(event).request_context.identity.sourceIp.unwrap()
```

The latter solution could be elaborated on, for example:

- Add a `__getitem__` to access items that aren't valid identifiers;
- Automatically unwrapping anything that isn't a `dict` or `None`;
- Turning `NamespaceWrapper` into a proxy object for the wrapped dict, so things like `len(w)`, `key in w` and iteration work;

... but I'm leaving that to you as an excercise.

Comment: I sort of like the first alternative thanks!

Comment: For the first function, you'll want to make sure `d.get(key)` is really returning a dict, or else you will throw errors. Use `isinstance(d, dict)` to check whether d is a dict, if it isn't return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.get` has two arguments. The second one is optional and defaults to `None`. Use empty dictionary instead to achieve safity during chaining. Here's an example:

```
result = event.get("request_context", dict()).get("identity", dict()).get("sourceIp")
```

Comment: oohh  - I like that!