# Using Python regex to parse a string for values where only some of the matches will be present

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a currency converter in Python for a game that parses a given string for amounts of various coins, and then tallies them all up into the smallest denomination.

```
Sample input: "5 royals 10 dollars 35 pennies"  
Resolves to: matches.group(2) == 5, matches.group(4) == 10, matches.group(7) == 35
```

The regex seems to pick them up just fine so no problem with that part:

```
matches = re.search(r"(?:(\d+) crowns)?(?:(\d+) royals)?(?:(\d+) ten-dollars)?(?:(\d+) dollars)?(?:(\d+) half-dollars)?(?:(\d+) ten-pence)?(?:(\d+) pennies)?", string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

but when I go on to add them up I hit a snag. I'd like to do something along the lines of:

```
pennies = matches.group(1) * 800000 + matches.group(2) * 10000 + matches.group(3) * 1000 + matches.group(4) * 100 + matches.group(5) * 50 + matches.group(6) * 10 + matches.group(7)
```

but that doesn't work since only some of the matches will have values for a given input, ie. "2 crowns 10 dollars 45 pennies", and the others will throw up a TypeError for trying to multiply None with an int.

I figured I'd get around it by checking if each value exists and adding them into the total one at a time, as ugly as it might look:

```
    if matches.group(7):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(7)))
    if matches.group(6):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(6)) * 10)
    if matches.group(5):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(5)) * 50)
    if matches.group(4):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(4)) * 100)
    if matches.group(3):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(3)) * 1000)
    if matches.group(2):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(2)) * 10000)
    if matches.group(1):
        pennies += (int(matches.group(1)) * 800000)
    return pennies
```

but only the largest (latest) denomination gets added and everything else ignored, for some reason that I can't figure out.

**Is there a better way to get around the fact that only some of the values will exist for a given run** since I can't assume they're there? It doesn't seem possible to give them a default value of 0 or anything. And **why does this sequence of if-statements only pick up the last existing denomination** and can it be fixed somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there example inputs and expected outputs (in text form)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator for some possible help.

Comment: Your input/regex is not working for me. So i cant try out the rest of the code

Comment: I'd change the way you use regex: Use a much simpler regex - something like `(\d+)\s+(pennies|royals|...)`, then find all matches of that, and use a lookup table from currency name -> value in the currency you're converting to.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Interesting, I tried giving them default values along the lines of "crowns  = int(matches.group(1)) if matches.group(1) is not None else 0" but got the exact same issue where only the last denomination is included. I think there has to be a problem with my regex syntax after all.

Comment: @Luatic Thanks for the suggestion! I'm too much of a novice to figure out how to do that in one sitting but I'll try it that way! I think there has to be a problem with my syntax even though regex101.com doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

Comment: I don't know Python but could you write something like `pennies += (int(matches.group(7) or '0'))`?

Answer (score 0):

Capture and evaluate the denomination also.

```
(?i)(\d+) (crowns|royals|ten-dollars|dollars|half-dollars|ten-pence|pennies)
```

```py
s = '5 royals 10 dollars 35 pennies'
p = '(?i)(\d+) (crowns|royals|ten-dollars|dollars|half-dollars|ten-pence|pennies)'
pennies = 0
for m in re.finditer(p, s):
    v = int(m.group(1))
    if m.group(2) == 'ten-pence': v *= 10
    elif m.group(2) == 'half-dollars': v *= 50
    elif m.group(2) == 'dollars': v *= 100
    elif m.group(2) == 'ten-dollars': v *= 1000
    elif m.group(2) == 'royals': v *= 10000
    elif m.group(2) == 'crowns': v *= 800000
    pennies += v
```