# Python: check if object exists in scope

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - checking variable existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/python-checking-variable-existing)

Is there an efficient, simple and pythonic way to check if an object exists in the scope?

In Python everything's an object (variables, functions, classes, class instances etc), so I'm looking for a generic existence test for an object, no matter what it is.

I half expected there to be an `exists()` [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#), but I couldn't find any to fit the bill.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you could always:

```
try:
    some_object
except NameError:
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: This is usually considered the "Pythonic" way of doing it.

Comment: This is efficient when in most cases the object does exist as catching an exception is a costly event

Answer (score 30):

You seem to be searching for [hasattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr).  You use it to see if, in the scope of the namespace of an object (and even imported modules are objects), a given attribute name exists.

So, I can do:

```
>>> import math
>>> hasattr(math, 'atan')
True
```

or something like:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.hello = None
... 
>>> myObj = MyClass()
>>> hasattr(myObj, 'hello')
True
>>> hasattr(myObj, 'goodbye')
False
```

Comment: Hah.  There's no answer talking about hasattr, so I craft one, making sure my examples work correctly, then post it, and POW! @Dog-eat-cat-world has beat me to it.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're looking for something like [locals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals). Here's how it works:

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> l = locals()
>>> print l
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'l': {...}, 
 '__package__': None,'__name__':'__main__', 'foo': 1, '__doc__': None}
>>> print l['foo']
1
```

Comment: You'll need to call locals to update the locals dictionary each time you want to check for existence, my guess would be that this is less efficient than the try-except method, although a benchmark is in order

Comment: it is better to use l.has_key('foo') for checking the existancy

Comment: The sequence of lookups that Python normally does for a name is `locals()`, `globals()`, and `vars(__builtin__)` -- so this is *not* checking to see if a name is currently in scope.

Comment: Just to clarify, to use `locals()` to find whether or not a variable exists you can do this: `'variable_name' in locals()`. it returns a boolean value indicating the variable's existance in the local namespace

Answer (score 5):

There will be a difference whether you are trying to determine if a local or a attribute of an object exists. For an object, hasattr(object, "attribute") will do the trick.

This also work on modules:

```
import math
hasattr(math,"pow") => True
```

But for what we can call the **main** scope, you will have to use locals(), as hasattr() need some sort of object to dig into. In this case there is none...

```
exists_mainscope = lambda name: locals().has_key(name)
exists_mainscope("test") => False
```

So, what you are looking for might be the following:

```
def exists(name,obj=None):
 if obj is None: return locals().has_key(name)
 else: return hasattr(obj,name)

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write your own:

```
import __builtin__
import sys

def exists(name):
    return (name in sys._getframe(1).f_locals  # caller's locals
         or name in sys._getframe(1).f_globals # caller's globals
         or name in vars(__builtin__)          # built-in
    )

if __name__=='__main__':
    def foobar():
        local_var = 42
        print 'exists("global_var"):', exists("global_var")
        print 'exists("local_var"):', exists("local_var")

    print 'exists("baz"):', exists("baz")  # undefined
    print 'exists("dict"):', exists("dict")  # built-in
    foobar()  # global_var doesn't exist yet
    global_var = 'I think, therefore I am'
    print 'exists("global_var"):', exists("global_var")
    foobar()  # now global_var exists
```