# Python objects life cycle tracing

Tags: python, trace

Is there any way to trace life cycle of objects during python code running? I know about sys.settrace function for setting callback, I can stop on each function call or line of code, but how can I get access to "living" objects during this? I would like to trace program so that I can do random checks after each stop, as if I really added code at stop place in sources.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. What kind of information are you trying to gather?

Comment: For example, at this step execution of program passed to func `func1` and 1 line allready runned in which object `obj1` of some type was created. I want to check this obj1, for example get results from `dir(obj1)` or check class of `obj1`

Comment: And you cannot do that with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`? That gives you an interactive debugger at that point. Object creation is itself not traceable, put traces in their `__init__` or `__new__` functions itself.

Comment: I want to trace program without modification of source code. I realized that i must add `pdb.set_trace()` to all functions in program, which i am tracing. Also i am interesting not in interactive tracing, i want to write code which extract needed data during execution.

Answer (score 2):

Up to some extend can be done by gc (garbage collector) module in CPython.

[Garbage Collector](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gc.html)
There are few functions using object as parameter and can provide some information regarding object existence:

```
gc.get_referrers(*objs)
gc.get_referents(*objs)
gc.is_tracked(obj)
```

To simply check if object exists use 'try' as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383379/python-check-if-object-exists-in-scope)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link was given to python documentation. Actually it would be better for me to comment on OP question but i don't have rights yet to do that. I will paste some information from link.