# How to check if a class member exists without getting exception

Tags: python

For primitive types I can use the if  in : boolean check.  But if I use the in syntax to check for the existence of a class member I get a NameError exception.  Is there a way in Python to check without an exception?  Or is the only way to surround in try except block?

Here is my sample code.

```
class myclass:
    i = 0
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.i = num

mylist = [1,2,3]
if 7 in mylist:
    print "found it"
else:
    print "7 not present"  #prints 7 not present


x = myclass(3)
print x.i       #prints 3

#below line NameError: name 'counter' is not defined
if counter in x:
    print "counter in x"
else:
    print "No counter in x"
```

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python

Comment: @fordprefect While it's probably a duplicate, it's not a duplicate of that question. This is about object attributes, that question is about local and global variables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you get is because you are using `counter` (a name) and not `'counter'` (the string). However, even if you were to use `'counter'` it would not do what you expect, you will get `TypeError: argument of type 'a' is not iterable` - that is you cannot iterate over your custom object.

Instead, use `hasattr` (thanks to Jon for the suggestion).

```
>>> x = A(3)
>>> x.i
3
>>> hasattr(x, 'counter')
False
>>> hasattr(x, 'i')
True
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr)

```
if hasattr(x, 'counter'):
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `__contains__` function in your class, which reports back what attributes are in the class using the `in` operator.

```
class myclass:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.i = num

    def __contains__(self, attribute_name):
        return hasattr(self, attribute_name)
```

Then (almost) the same as your code would work well.

```
x = myclass(3)
print x.i       #prints 3

# prints 'No counter in x'
if 'counter' in x:
    print "counter in x"
else:
    print "No counter in x"
```

Note that you need to pass the string of the attribute name, rather than the attribute itself.

Comment: Your contains idea is interesting but I think it is easier to just use hasattr directly.  I didn't know about hasattr

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your question depends a bit on what you mean by a member existing in an object. If you mean, does an instance variable exist on a given object, use `hasattr` as other answers have explained.

However, if you're creating your own collection type and want to check for a specific value in its contents, then you'll want to give your class a `__contains__` method. That magic method is called to implement the `in` operator. Here's a trivial example, where I simply wrap up a list in my own object.

```
class MyListWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable=[]):
        self.list = list(iterable)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self.list
```

Test session:

```
>>> m = MyListWrapper(["foo", "bar"])
>>> "foo" in m
True
```