# How do I check if a static variable exists in Python?

Tags: python, static-members

This is a related question: [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python)

However, it did not work well for static variables.

What I am trying to do is the following,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        if A.var is null: # this does not work, okay
            A.var = 'foo'
            print 'assigned'
```

Okay, since `A.var` is not even assigned. It raises en error. So, I tried this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        if 'A.var' not in globals(): # this seems to okay, but ..
            A.var = 'foo'
            print 'assigned'

a = A()
b = A()
```

It results:

```
assigned
assigned
```

Which shows that `if 'A.var' not in globals():` line not working properly.

So, how do I check if a static variable exists in Python?

Comment: Python doesn't have static variables, so... you don't.

Comment: There's no such thing as a static variable in python - a variable on a class is simply called a class variable. No `null` either (it's called `None`). Also, you're looking for `hasattr`.

Comment: also, how can a class' attribute be assigned before the `__init__` function call?

Comment: Technically `A.var` is a class variable, not a static variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either you use [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
if not hasattr(A, 'var'):
    A.var = 'foo'
```

or, as some would prefer according to the "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" principle:

```
try:
    A.var
except NameError:
    A.var = 'foo'
```

Finally, you can simply define the default value in the class body:

```
class A(object):
    var = None
    ...

if A.var is None:
    a.var = 'foo'
```

(Note that neither approach is thread-safe)

Comment: the `try... except` approach is so easy and simple I can't understand why someone would look for anything else

Comment: Upvoted for `hasattr`, although I disagree with prefering the `try/except` approach - `hasattr` is shorter, more readable and more explicit.

Comment: After a little more thought I think the EAFP approach is not only disagreeable but simply wrong in this case. You're not doing anything that requires permission as setting the attribute is always possible (given `A` has no restrictions on setting attributes of course). Thus you even have to use a nonsensical statement, accessing the attribute without using it in any way, to test for "permission". But actually you just want to check if a condition is met, with the condition being "attribute x has been set" - which directly translates to the above if statement.

Comment: @l4mpi yes, apparently, in this case you're right. On the other hand, if we had a function than returns `A.var` and sets the attribute if it's missing, `try...catch` would make more sense.