# Why is an indeterminate state of existence of a variable bad programming?

Tags: python

And more to the point, how do I avoid it?

See the link below for further reference; specifically the reply by paxdiablo.
[How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python)

As you probably guessed, I have a scenario where I've programmed a web page that has a variable whose existence is unknown at run time.
What is happening is, a user uploads information that can be in several different formats.  To be more concrete, an address.  For example, the street may have a directional (southwest, north), and the address may have a condo qualifier (unit#2F).  These (or things/scenarios like them) will be assigned to and represented by different variables.  As the data is manipulated in my code, I have conditionals

```
if street_dir_var:
    #do something
```

Hence my question(s):  why is this bad form, and whats a proper substitute?

PS - if it matters, I'm coding in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditionals are fine.  The issue is if `street_dir_var` is not even defined, that line will throw a `NameError`.  You can *technically* catch `NameError`, but that makes for messy unmaintainable code.  It also suggests that you are [putting data into your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html), which is a bad code smell.

In general, a variable should be defined in any logical branch that tries to access it.  If it "doesn't apply" for whatever reason, it should at very least be `None`.  This serves as a fine default value for your variables, and often serves as a default for keyword arguments which need one.

To get more specific here:

> These (or things/scenarios like them) will be assigned to and
>   represented by different variables.

Really bad code smell.  All those variables represent data for a **single address** - you need to aggregate all those variables into a *single* variable, be it a class, a `list`, a `dict`, or a `namedtuple`.

```
class Address:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.street = kwargs.get('street')
       self.directional = kwargs.get('directional')
       self.condo = kwargs.get('condo')

user_data = parse_data(some_data_source) # user_data looks like a dict

address = Address(**user_data)
```

One address, one container.  `address.condo` might be `None`, but at least it's defined when I ask for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm a beginning programmer so coding with a paradigm in mind is difficult.  Usually, I just want the code to work.  Can you explain briefly why different parts of an address being represented by different variables has a "really bad code odor"??  Specifically, what problems does it cause?

Comment: The point is that you need to collect all those variables together into one object.  Doing this makes your code easier to read and FAR easier to maintain/refactor.  Hard to explain more without writing an essay, I'm afraid.  Do more research on Object-Oriented Programming and maybe come back to this problem in a few weeks, see if it makes any more sense to you then.