# How to say "if var:" even if "var" does not exist at all?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This will work fine:

```
a = 1
if a:
  b = a
```

but this will not work:

```
if a:
  b = a
```

it is not like this "if" statement will be executed given that we are explicitly saying..

```
 "if a exists"
```

so why does it error ? if it does not exist then simply do not do anything within the parameters of that if statement.

**UPDATE**

it turns out "if a" means.. "if a value for a" means in python.

i am looking for the equivalency for "if a exists at all then move forward"

Comment: You are **not** saying 'if `a` exists'. You are asking if the *value `a` references is true or false*. Names reference objects, objects have a boolean value.

Comment: Why do you need to know if a name is defined? It sounds as if you want to do `a = None` first instead.

Comment: Use None or some other value as your "not set yet" value.

Comment: Good primer on Python names: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @user4003832 no, you're saying *"does the object referenced by the name `a` evaluate True-y or False-y?"* If the name `a` isn't assigned, you get a `NameError`.

Comment: @user4003832: no, you are [testing for boolean truth](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). The value exists, but it may be a value that is considered false (empty, numeric 0, `False` or `None`).

Comment: when at school someones name is called.. if no answer is given.. they are not present at all. what is the equivalency of that ?

Comment: You could catch `NameError`. But the point is that this simply isn't how you usually code in Python. You should *know" whether `a` is defined at that point or not, and if that means assigning `None` to it earlier on, so be it.

Comment: Variables are not school students, and attempting to code by an analogy between them is not helpful.

Comment: @user4003832: A teacher trying to resolve a bunch of names into actual pupils is very far removed from a program using names. Sounds like you want to store stuff in a dictionary instead and test for keys being present. `if keyname in dictionary:` is far closer to `if pupil present in class`.

Comment: You're trying to impose *your* ideas of how things are supposed to work on Python here. You won't have any success with that (in any language for that matter).

Comment: can i at least set the "a" to "0" or something and "if a:" will not execute as a result ?

Comment: found something with lots of votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
if 'a' in locals():
    # variable 'a' is defined
```

You can also use Python's principle that it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission:

```
try:
    b
    # if we get here, variable 'b' is defined
except NameError:
    # variable 'b' is not defined
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements.

Answer (score 3):

When a name *doesn't exist* (hasn't been bound to, so there are no assignments binding a value to it, no `import` statements exist that assign an imported object to the name and no function arguments exist), then Python throws an exception.

You can handle that exception; a global name throws [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError), a local name throws an [`UnboundLocalError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.UnboundLocalError). Catching the exception with a `try...except` statement also can tell you if the exception wasn't thrown:

```
try:
    somename
except NameError:
    # name does not exist
else:
    # name exists
```

See the [*Execution model* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) on what makes a name exist or not.