# Checking if a key in dict is defined or not

Tags: python

So I have a `P = dict()`. I have the following code:

```
def someFunction():
    P['key'] += 1
    '''do other task'''
```

What is the simplest way to check if `P['key']`  is defined or not?

I checked [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-python) but I am not sure if that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

Two main ways to check in an ordinary dict:

The "look before you leap" paradigm. The else statement isn't required, of course, unless you want to define some alternate behavior:

```
if 'key' in P:
    P['key'] += 1
else:
    pass
```

The "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" paradigm:

```
try:
    P['key'] += 1
except KeyError:
    pass  # Or do something else
```

Or you could use a `defaultdict` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `defaultdict` from the collections module.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
d[0] = 5
d[1] = 10

for i in range(3):
    d[i] += 1

# Note that d[2] was not set before the loop

for k, v in d.items():
    print('%i: %i' % (k,v))
```

prints:

```
brunsgaard@archbook /tmp> python test.py
0: 6
1: 11
2: 1
```

Comment: This of course assumes that the reason the OP wants to check for `'key' in P` is to decide if he should be using `+= 1` or `= 1` :)

Comment: @dano, not really. You would just modify you constructor to the defaultdict like so `defaultdict(lambda: 1)`.

Comment: @brunsgaard it does assume that OP wants to initialize the value if it doesn't exist, rather than just skipping it (or doing something else).

Comment: @JesseMu Right, that's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I will check key presence with

```
if some_key in some_dict:
    print("do something")
```

Advanced usage: If you have a dictionary, key is string, value is a list. When key exists, you want to add an element to key associated value list. So you can

```
some_dict[some_key] = some_dict.get(some_key, []) + [new_item];
```