# Inventory command in currency system. (Discordpy)

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so im making an inventory command for my currency sys but im stuck with it. How should i exactly define that if user has nothing in his inv?

My code:

```
bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"] # This is just the json where the items are stored.
for item in bag:
            name = item["item"]
            amount = item["amount"]

            if name in bag == None:
                em.add_field(name="Your bag is empty.")
            else:
                em.add_field(name=name,value=amount)

        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

> Traceback:
> No errors in console, it simply does not work.

Comment: you mean something like `if (name := item.get('item')) is None`?

Comment: Would not an empty `bag` mean there's nothing in inventory? What's the type of `bag`?

Comment: bag is the json, where the items are stored. bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]

Comment: @timgeb Yeah but that is the same as my code, no error just simply does not work.

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format, not a type. What type is `bag`? `dict`? `set`? `list`? Something else? [Sample code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be complete.

Comment: its a dict like this: {"822532757011300383": {"wallet": 321, "bank": 0}}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Checking if a 'Dictionary' is empty doesn't seem to work](//stackoverflow.com/q/23177439/90527)

Comment: @outis I tried alll the suggestions there but it still hasnt solved my problem..

Comment: Note the question is still unclear due to both the description and code being underspecified. Based on the answer, this question is a duplicate of "[Checking if a key in dict is defined or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26247933/90527)". Also, there's a code smell in that the item both comes from the bag and provides a key of something in the bag (which is the form of a linked list).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The solution:

```
if not name in bag:
```

> Explaining: "name in bag" returns a bool, and it will be never "None".