# Testing for presence of IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I have the same code, which I occasionally run from the command line as `python source.py` and occasionally copy/paste it into interactive IPython. I would like to execute slightly different code in either way, and tried to embed differences into the following code block:

```
try:
    __IPYTHON__
    # do IPython-mode code
except NameError:
    # do script-mode code
```

I know that in Python this is a common technique, but it screws up automated flagging in PyCharm and I was hoping to find some more attractive way to test for the presence of IPython, perhaps by testing `'__IPYTHON__' in ...` or something similar. However, I saw that this symbol is neither in `locals()` nor in `globals()`. Is there any other place I can test for its presence, or any other more conventional test, not using exceptions directly?

I am using Python 2.7.11 and IPython 5.1.0.
Thank you very much.

**UPDATE** Related but unhelpful: [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: try the global function `get_ipython()`, it exists only on ipython, not the normal shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
if hasattr(__builtins__, '__IPYTHON__'):
    print('IPython')
else:
    print('Nope')
```

Answer (score 4):

While the current accepted answer works in the `__main__` namespace, it won't work in a package due to [`__builtins__` being a dict in other namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution). This should work in any namespace in python3:

```py
import builtins
getattr(builtins, "__IPYTHON__", False)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i really appreciate it, +1