# Function for test if variable exist

Tags: python, function, variables

Is it possible to make a python function that check if variable exist ?

I tried this but its dont working :

```
def tst(x):
 try: x
 except NameError:
  x = raw_input("%s: " % x)
 return x
```

Do there's a way for do that , or i will everytime have to try and except error ?

Thx

Comment: You pass a variable to the function which checks whether this variable exists... Where's the logic???

Comment: You're obviously new (1 reputation point) so it's a bit harsh to vote your question down. But people have because it doesn't show basic research or understanding of Python. It's important to do a bit of homework before asking questions.

Your issue is that you're defining a function to test a variable. The function can only test the argument (locally bound name for the variable passed to it). So it will never fail in the function. It will fail at the site where the function is called if the variable isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you should probably consider what you're trying to accomplish, you could use something like this:

```
if x in locals() or x in globals():
    ...
```

Comment: You need to test by name of the variable, not content, e.g., 'x' in locals().

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that python will declare a new variable x so you will never encounter a NameError.

[A solution for this already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: If a solution already exists within the Stack network, please flag the question as a duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks, and done.

Comment: It's not the same question.  He's asking how to write a function that tests if a variable exists not how to check if a variable exists.  The problem is if you pass the potentially undefined variable to the function, how do you even refer to it from inside the function