# Checking if an environment variable exists and is set to True

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, environment-variables

So, I want to check and verify if a given variable "abc" exists and that it's true. If the variable exist and is False, then I want it to go to else. Here is how I got it to work in python:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
if "abc" in env and env['abc'] == "True":
    print "Works"
else:
    print "Doesn't work"
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `env.get('abc', False) == True`

Comment: that string of identical answers all within 10sec of eachother was impressive...

Comment: Are you actually looking for a string of the value "True", or are you looking for a boolean `True`?

Comment: If `env` is `os.environ` and these are literally environment variables, it'll be a string `"True"`, but it's not clear what `env` is and what preprocessing may have been done.

Comment: @idjaw I think because I am checking for env variable I am not sure if I can check for boolean!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: @VictorC. I tried your below suggestion in Python 2.7.9 but doesn't work there. Essentially I want something that works on 2.7 and 3.0

Comment: @Jason That's strange, `locals()` and `globals()` exists in Python 2.7 as well...it works for me when I try it with version 2.7. What error are you getting?

Comment: @VictorC. So I did an export abc=True but the locals().get('abc') gives me null in 2.7.9. Do you have any other imports apart from sys or os?

Comment: @VictorC. Now I understand how locals and globals work. Given that I am not sure if there is a need for locals or globals as I can just do `env.get('abc')`. But that still leaves the "True" or "False" open as any of the output here doesnt check if the variable is True/False. How do I go to else if the variable exist and is False ?

Comment: @Jason `os.environ` is still a dictionary similar to local variables. You can do the same thing you did with globals, namely `if env.get('abc')=='True'`

Comment: `os.environ.get('abc') or None` will work as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check to see if the variable is in the dictionaries returned by `globals()` and `locals()`. (Thank you to Aaron for reminding me to add the full code)

For a local variable:

```
if locals().get('abc'):
    print(abc)
```

For a global variable:

```
if globals().get('abc'):
    print(abc)
```

For an environment variable:

```
if os.environ.get('abc')=='True':
    #abc is set to True
```

More information here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals

Comment: the full answer would then look like `if locals().get('abc') == True:` (or `...globals()...`)

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
env.get("abc", False)
```

False is the default value if "abc" is not in env.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Try Except Block.

```
try:
    # Try calling ABC here anyway you like
    # Here I am just printing it
    print(abc)
except NameError:
    print("Variable ABC does not exist")
```

Comment: If you do it this way, you should do `except NameError:` instead of blindly catching any exception

Answer (score 0):

It's enough get it from env, I think

```
env.get('abc')
```