# Check if variable is defined using a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to check, whether variable is defined or not. If it is not, then this variable should be created as empty string.
I want to do it by `try` and it works fine:

```
try:
    ident
except:
    ident = ''
```

But I need to do that using a function, coz I will do that many, many times and it will became unreadable.

Doing it like below can't work, coz it will not go into the function, if `ident` does not exist.

```
def absence_of_tag(ident):
    try:
        ident
    except:
        return ''
```

I was also trying to do it with `*args`, like that:

```
def absence_of_tag(*args):
    try:
        args
    except:
        return ''
```

and then call it by:

```
ident = absence_of_tag(ident)
```

I thought, it will go into the `except` in function, but still it gave me `NameError: name 'ident' is not defined`

Do you have any idea how to do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists

Comment: you can check `globals()` and `locals()` for the variable if you have its name as a string. So `'ident' in globals()` would  return true if a variable named `ident` exists in the global scope.

However, why do you even need this? Usually, one should avoid using variables that aren't defined in every case.

Comment: You should not need to check whether variables exist or not all that much anyway; you should ensure your variables are initialised and then not worry about it. Further, your example use case with "the def" is a completely different issue. If `ident` in `absence_of_tag(ident)` is not defined (in the caller), there's nothing the body of that function can do about it.

Comment: Please stop calling this a "def" or a "definition". It's a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner, you can perhaps go with:

```
ident= ident if ident else ' '
```

EDIT: This also worked for me:

```
f=lambda x: x if x else ' '

c=8

f(c)     
# output: 8

f(d)    
# NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```