# variable referenced before assignment error in python

Tags: python

In my code I am testing if a user has AWS access keys:

```
for response in paginator.paginate(UserName=user_name):
    if len(response['AccessKeyMetadata']) and 'AccessKeyId' in response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0].keys():
        key1 = response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['AccessKeyId']
```

Later in my code I test if key1 exists:

```
if key1:
    print("\nAccess Key 1: ", key1)
else:
    print("The user does not have any keys.")
```

If the user has NO keys at all, the function fails with this error:

```
  File ".\aws_iam_utils.py", line 1430, in rotate_access_keys
    if key1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key1' referenced before assignment
```

Am I testing if key1 exists correctly? Why am I getting an unbound local error, when it should just print out the statement in the else clause?

Comment: [mcve]. Is this in a different function?

Comment: No, it's all in one function that this error occurs.

Comment: With `if key:` you don't ask if the variable `key1` exists. You assume that the variable exists and ask if it has a _truthy_ value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if key1:` does not test if `key1` exists; it tests if it contains a "truthy" value, and assumes that it *does* exist.

Comment: Ok thanks. How can I test if a variable exists?

Comment: You better don't. Make it exist and set it to a value like `None`.

Comment: @bluethundr you check if exists using the idioms in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/843293/10553976 and I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You just need to initialise `key1` before the `if` condition i.e.

```
key1 = None  # <- You need this line
for response in paginator.paginate(UserName=user_name):
    if len(response['AccessKeyMetadata']) and 'AccessKeyId' in response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0].keys():
        key1 = response['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['AccessKeyId']
```

It is because if the `if` condition is not met, `key1` will not be created in your original code.

Comment: OK thanks. Is it possible to test if a variable exists? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the difference between `None` and `null` or `undefined`. Consider three toilet paper holders. One has plenty, one is down to the inner cardboard tube, and one has not even the tube. Or put another way, one has `int` papers, one has `None` papers, and one is `null` or `undefined`.

As mentioned in the other answer, initialize `key1` as `None` before your `if` statement to fix it.

```
key1 = None
```

To check if a variable exists:

```
if 'key1' in globals():
    print(key1) # Or whatever
```