# How to pass parameters into EXCEPT from TRY

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a function:

```
def UPLOAD(FILE_NAME):


    try:

        client = bigquery.Client()

        dataset_ref = client.dataset(DATASET)
        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(TABLE)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
        job_config.autodetect = False

        with open(FILE_NAME, 'rb') as source_file:
            job = client.load_table_from_file(
                source_file,
                table_ref,
                location='EU',  # Must match the destination dataset location.
                job_config=job_config)  # API request

        job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

    except:
        error(job,'BLABLA')
```

The issue in this function that when I try to pass the `job` parameter from except to error function it not picking it up.

What is the actual error, I'm not sure...

**ERROR: Error: local variable 'job' referenced before assignment**

UPDATE:

```
def error(job,extra):
    if extra == 'BLABLA':
        ERROR = job.error
    elif extra == 'LALA':
        ERROR = job.error
    else:
        print('else')
```

Comment: Well, where does `extra` come from? Where is it declared?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 have added error function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: There is a possibility that exception occured far before you declare job with `job = client.load_table_from_file` .It is more secure to check whether that variable is defined at the time of exception since python scope is a bit different than C/Java/C# or relevant other language scopes.

Comment: @FallenAngel thank you for your suggestion, I have fixed the issue by lower down `try:`. Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried defining `job` at the start of your try statement?
it seems that the exception is happening well before the variable has even been defined, so the try statement is exiting before `job` even exists!!