# How to know if '__file__' is in the namespace

Tags: python

I have the following statement:

```
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir, os.pardir)))
```

However, occasionally `__file__` will not be defined in the namespace:

> `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

What would be the best way to check for this? The first thing that came to mind was `if '__file__' in globals()`.

Comment: When is `__file__` not defined? Could you provide the arguments you passed to the python interpreter? The only case I can imagine is running in the REPL (which appears to be the case with the `>>>`). In that case, I suppose you could just try-catch and just use the cwd as your base path.

Comment: It would help to have the context here, but this seems like [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Manipulating the pythonpath from within a python program is usually a sign of something not being set up properly...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: @101arrowz yes, this was a script copy-pasted into the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, a fairly pythonic way to test if a name exists is to catch the exception:

```
from pathlib import Path

try:
    value = Path(__file__, '..', '..').resolve().absolute()
except NameError:
    value = os.getenv('TMPDIR', '/tmp/foo')
```

Comment: thanks. What's the advantage of using `Path` over `os.path` ?

Comment: @David542 it's essentially the same thing but it's a much cleaner, object-oriented API. I haven't used `os.path` in years