# python:class member variable null or undefined

Tags: python, class, null, undefined

I am new in python and creating a class which have few variables but in my process method in want check whether few member variables are being set or not. Just like java script undefined or if i can set null.  I don't want to use any default values: how i can check null or undefined?

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, name, city):
      self.name = name
      self.city = city

  def setState(self,state)
      self.state = state

  def process(self):
      print("Name:", name)
    # here i want check whether state is being  set or not. 
    # How can i do it. I tried  if self.state is None but getting 
    # exception AttributeError.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hasattr`

```
if hasattr(self, 'state'):
    ...
```

or catch the `AttributeError`  yourself (which, really, is all that `hasattr` does):

```
try:
    x = self.state
except AttributeError:
    print("No state")
else:
    print(f"State is {x}")
```

However, it's far better to simply initialize the attribute to `None` in the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, name, city):
    self.name = name
    self.city = city
    self.state = None
```

Then you can simply check the value of `self.state` as necessary.

```
if self.state is not None:
    ...
```

As an aside, unless you want to perform some sort of validation on the value of `state`, just let the user access `self.state` directly rather than using a method to set the value.

```
x = MyClass("bob", "Townsville")
x.state = "Vermont"  # rather than x.setState("Vermont")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if variables are being set by using

```py
def process(self):
    print('Name:',name)
    if self.state is not None :
        print('State:': self.state)
```

is None is python's way of checking if something was set or not

Comment: Thanks it worked but needed one more steps.
I set state = None in constructor and then
```
if self.state is not None :
        print('State:': self.state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked but needed one more steps.
I set state = None in constructor and then

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, name, city):
      self.name = name
      self.city = city
      self.state = None

def process(self):
    print('Name:',name)
    if self.state is not None :
        print('State:': self.state)
```