# Way to check if a list exists after deleting it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to see if there's a way I can see if the list got deleted after doing del command on the list

```
  del users
  if bool(users):
      print("exist")
```

One of the ways that I tried is mentioned above. But for each of these, I get an error-

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'users' referenced before assignment

Since the list is not present, it is unable to reference it but I wanted to know if there's a way(an in-built method) I can check if it got deleted( not empty)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: Why do you need to test that the variable is inexistent after deleting it? Any reason to believe this shouldn't be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try-except statement to catch the error:

```
    test = [1, 2, 3]
    del test
    try:
        test
        print('Test exists!')
    except NameError:
        print("It's deleted!")
```

Comment: Okay, so this is an error-handling thing. I was looking for a method, if there was one, using which this could be done.  But thanks for that. I think this is good.