# Check if have another browser opened on python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can i validate if I have another browser opened on my python code using selenium.
i create a function to call the webdrive

but the browser have not open before called

```
def OpenDriver():
    if not drive:   
        drive = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        return drive
    else:
        return drive
pass    

def site():
    navega().get("https://www.google.com/")
pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to check if `drive` variable exists.
So you should change from

```py
if not drive:
```

to

```py
if drive in locals() or drive in globals():
```

See more explanations about checking local and global variables existance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843293/3485434)

Comment: Thank you. I'm going try this solution

Comment: Sure. Let me know if that worked or you still need some help