# Balance between dictionary size and memory consumption

Tags: python, algorithm, memory, data-structures, dictionary

I'm using a [`memoized` decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) to cache repeated calls. I'm seeing about a 4x execution speedup due to memoization on some moderate-sized test cases.

With larger test cases, the memoized dictionary mapping inputs to outputs takes up a considerable amount of memory, to the point where I'm getting `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"` errors (I'm using Jython).

I can save some memory by using `memoized_cache[hash(key)] = value` rather than `memoized_cache[key]: value`, assuming that `hash(key)` is fewer bytes than `key`. As pointed out by @gnibbler, this will cause problems if there are hash collisions.

The other memory savings I can introduce is limiting the size of the dictionary to a fixed number of items. Such a [SizedDict recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/496842-sized-dictionary/?c=15571) already exists, but I'd like to truncate elements that are accessed the least often.

Here's what I have written:

```
from collections import Counter

class FrequencySizedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, size=1000):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self._maxsize = size
        self._counter = Counter()
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self._counter[key] += 1
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    def resize(self, size):
        keys = list(self._counter.most_common(size))
        items = [(key, dict.__getitem__(self, key)) for key in keys]
        self.clear()
        dict.update(self, items)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(self._queue) >= self._maxsize:
            self.resize(self._maxsize/2)
        self._counter[key] += 1
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

Is there a better data way to implement this with less memory or time overhead? `resize` is quite expensive: `O(n log n)`

Comment: `memoized_cache[hash(key)]` will cause interesting bugs when you have a hash collison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

> @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)
>
> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.

Or [pylru](https://github.com/jlhutch/pylru) as described in the answer [memoization library for python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815873/memoization-library-for-python-2-7)

Comment: This is the best answer for Python3.2+ Unfortunately Jython isn't there yet.

Comment: Woops, didn't realize it was a Py3 only feature. added a link to a library that should work with Jython

Comment: I'm really looking for a Least Frequently Used cache algorithm, but this answer put me on the right track of what to look for. This LFU implementation looks somewhat similar to my original code: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/, using a Counter to keep track of how frequently an item is accessed.