# How can I combine lazy short circuiting with caching in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a condition like the following:

```
if limit > current and expensive_function() is not None:
    logging.debug('Limit:%s Current:%s Expensive_Result:%s',
                  limit,
                  current,
                  expensive_function())
    current += 1
```

I put `expensive_function()` at the end of the conditional because it is expensive. How can I cache the value to not reiterate over it when logging?

I have considered breaking up the conditional into two, but I am worried it's making the code less readable:

```
if limit > current:
    expensive_result = expensive_function()
    if expensive_result is not None:
         logging.debug('Limit:%s Current:%s Expensive_Result:%s',
                       limit,
                       current,
                       expensive_result)
         current += 1
```

Comment: The first thing you should consider is whether `expensive_function` is really so very expensive to be worth the added complexity. Another fairly clean option is to make a memoized version of `expensive_function` as outline here http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php, for instance (you probably don't need to go as far as making it a decorator for one-off use)

Comment: I don't think there's any better way to avoid calling `expensive_function` twice than what you have in your second code block.

Comment: @pvg Unfortunately, I didn't think to put that this is also python 2.7, and apparently memoization doesn't come with that by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815873/memoization-library-for-python-2-7

Comment: @Bamcclur you don't need the decorator, just the return-a-closure thing will work fine in python2.7

Comment: Or if you find it too funky, just make it a class and use an ivar to hold onto the result. so then you'd just have instance.check_expensive_result(); anytime you want a full recalc, make a new instance.

Comment: Ah okay, so would implementing expensive functions with memoization be a good practice to keep doing to keep things fast?

Comment: Your second block looks perfectly readable to me.

Comment: @Bamcclur it really depends how expensive and how often you need to memoize. The implementation with the check that you have now is perfectly reasonable too, as other have said. You can make it even simpler by removing the None check since, stylistically, log level 'debug' is for logging just about everything that happens. Long story short, don't overthink this and worry about performance after you've got things working and done some profiling.