# Given recursive expression, find algorithm with space complexity O(1)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have been given the task to write an algorithm given this simple expression:

```
f (0) = 0, f (1) = 1, f (2n) = f (n), f (2n + 1) = f (n) + f (n + 1).
```

The restrictions are: Time Complexity O(logn), Space Complexity O(1).
I wrote this basic recursion function:

```
int func (int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return func(n / 2);
    } else {
        return func(n / 2) + func((n / 2) + 1);
    }
}
```

There is probably something smarter using an iterative algorithm because I need O(1) space complexity (I think my code is not O(1) space because of the recursive calls).

Comment: Observe that with an even argument you can divide it by two until it's odd, and only then call the function. Apply same logic to the odd argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently generating Stern's Diatomic Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229066/efficiently-generating-sterns-diatomic-sequence)

Comment: I answered, but then searched for dupes and found one. Note that the accepted answer there is poor, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557597/1400793 provides a solution that's a little simpler than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence is Stern's diatomic sequence, and the function you've been given is called `fusc(n)`.

One way to compute it in O(log n) time and O(1) space complexity is to find the n'th value in the Calkin-Wilf tree. That value's numerator will be `fusc(n)`. You can read some background on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree

Here's some code that checks the naive `fusc` implementation with the fast version. It's in Python, but it would be trivial to convert to C++.

```
def fusc(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    if n%2 == 0:
        return fusc(n//2)
    return fusc(n//2) + fusc(n//2+1)


def fast_fusc(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    top = 1
    while top <= n:
        top <<= 1
    top >>= 1
    a, b = 1, 1
    while top > 1:
        top >>= 1
        if n & top:
            a, b = a + b, b
        else:
            a, b = a, a + b
    return a


for i in xrange(100):
    assert fusc(i) == fast_fusc(i)
```

You can see that in `fast_fusc`, `top` iterates over the bits of `n`, so the code performs O(log n) arithmetic operations. There's only 4 variables used (`n`, `a`, `b`, `top`) so it uses O(1) space.