# An  ×  chessboard is to be cut into its · unit squares

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, greedy, divide-and-conquer

An  ×  chessboard is to be cut into its · unit squares. At each step, you can make either one horizontal cut or one vertical cut. The first cut will split the board into two sub-boards; after that each cut splits one remaining sub-board into two. The cost of a cut equals the number of unit squares remaining in the smaller of the two resulting sub-boards. For example, a horizontal cut on a 2 × 3 board results in two 1 × 3 sub-boards and costs 3, whereas a vertical cut results in sub-boards of dimensions 2 × 1 and 2 × 2 and costs 2. Costs are additive: the cost of a sequence of cuts equals the sum of their individual costs. Describe an algorithm to compute the minimum total cost of reducing the  ×  board into its unit squares. Prove its correctness and show your analysis of its time complexity.

My solution goes as follows:
1. I follow the greedy approach of checking for the highest between m (row) and n (column) and making a cut. 
2. If m is higher I make a vertical cut and other a horizontal cut.
3. This gives me the lowest cut cost in every step.
4. I follow divide and conquer and recursively follow the approach until I have m x n = 1 x 1

This seems to be working but what I am struggling with is to derive the time complexity and proving the correctness of my algorithm.

My expression of time complexity is T(m*n) = 2 T(m*n/2) + theta(n).

Can someone advice me how I can do this?

Comment: That is what I believe too. But couldn't prove that mathematically yet so didn't state that explicitly. May be if I can derive the complexity I can take a shot at proving that.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum cost is `(n-1)*m+(m-1)*n`. You can obtain by making `m` horizontal cuts paying for every one `n-1` and `n` vertical cuts paying for every one `m-1`. That is **O(1)** algorithm.

To cut off a one unit square you need to pay at least 2 for it in `(n-1)*(m-1)` cases, at least 1 in `(n-1)+(m-1)`, and one unit square you can get for free. This bounds overall price from below:

```
2*(n-1)*(m-1)+1*(n-1)+(m-1)+0*1 = 2*n*m-n-m = (n-1)*m+(m-1)*n
```

Comment: FYI, yours and Gassa's seem to match for `i,j` in range 2-100: https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/ExperiencedUnfoldedBrain

Comment: So you are saying its O(mn) for this scenario?

Comment: @AyanSengupta it's O(1), it's a straight formula!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic programming approach which works in `O (m * n * (m + n))`.

For each possible size `w * h` of a sub-rectangle, compute the cost `f (w, h)` of cutting it into individual squares.
Choose the first cut: `w * h` is cut either into `a * h` and `b * h`, or into `w * c` and `w * d`.
The cost of cutting into `a * h` and `b * h` is `min (a, b) * h + f (a, h) + f (b, h)`.
The cost of cutting into `w * c` and `w * d` is `w * min (c, d) + f (w, c) + f (w, d)`.
Putting all that together, we have

```
f (w, h) = min of
                min {for every a such that 0 < a < w}
                    (let b = w - a)
                    min (a, b) * h + f (a, h) + f (b, h)
           and
                min {for every c such that 0 < c < h}
                    (let d = h - c)
                    w * min (c, d) + f (w, c) + f (w, d)
```

The base is `f (1, 1) = 0`.

We can store all `f (w, h)` as a two-dimensional array and calculate them bottom-up in two loops, like this:

```
for w = 1, 2, ..., m:
    for h = 1, 2, ..., n:
        calculate f[w][h] by the formula above in O (w + h)
```

Or write a recursive function with memoization.

Any of the two approaches will work in `O (m * n * (m + n))`: we have to calculate `m * n` values, and each one is calculated as a minimum of `O (m + n)` values.

---

If the greedy approach actually works (I don't know), it would do so in O (log m + log n).
By intuitive argument, for example, if `m = 17` and `n = 23`, then the following rectangles must be considered:

```
17 * 23
17 * 11 and 17 * 12
 8 * 11 and  8 * 12 and  9 * 11 and  9 * 12
 8 *  5 and  8 *  6 and  9 *  5 and  9 *  6
 4 *  5 and  4 *  6 and  5 *  5 and  5 *  6
 4 *  2 and  4 *  3 and  5 *  2 and  5 *  3
 2 *  2 and  2 *  3 and  3 *  2 and  3 *  3
 1 *  1 and  1 *  2 and  2 *  1 and  2 *  2
 1 *  1 again
```

As we can see, the rectangles will be of the form `(m / 2^x) * (n / 2^y)`, where `x` and `y` are between `0` and `log_2 (m + n)`, and the rounding can go either way.

Comment: I tried to implement your algorithm here: https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/BlankFreshLicense but I'm getting 13 for `f(2,3)`, where I think the answer is 7. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @גלעדברקן It's base case = 0 instead of 1. I made that error too, but edited it away during the five-minute grace period. Turns out it's a common one ;) .

Comment: @גלעדברקן And thank you for actually implementing the pseudocode! Also, I'd like to note that, using Python 3.2+ or [some backport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11815873/1488799) to Python 2.7, it is possible to get a one-liner memoization with `lrucache`. Which we should do anyway for larger sizes to make the solution polynomial instead of exponential.

Comment: Cool. I just wanted to compare to the greedy so I'm not concerned about efficiency, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: FYI, yours and Yola's seem to match for `i,j` in range 2-100: https://repl.it/@gl_dbrqn/ExperiencedUnfoldedBrain

Comment: @Gassa thank you for your detailed explanation. I thought of dynamic programming but didn't go for it. Let me explain why. Dynamic programming would help me compute cut costs and store it for future reference that would take constant time. However, in this scenario, while making a cut, computing the cost also take constant time since a board of M x N will either result in M x N-1 and 1 x N sub - board or M-1 x N and M x 1 sub-board. The cost of the cut in either case is either M or N which can be computed in constant time. What do you think of this?

Comment: @AyanSengupta Yeah, now that I understand it, I think the other answer by Yola is right in essence (albeit insignificantly off in details). And as it is the theoretical lower bound, dynamic programming is an overkill. So you can disregard my answer altogether. The only benefit of dynamic programming here is that the approach would still work for other cost functions, when there is no obvious greedy solution.