# How to check in python if variable is not None and greater than something in one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How make this statement in one line?

```
if x is not None:
    if x > 0:
        pass
```

if I write with just 'and' it shows exception if None

```
if x is not None and x > 0:
     pass
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem and is runnable. What is `x` in your case?

Comment: Not reproduceable: `if x is not None and x > 0: print("Not None")` + `else: print(None)` works for integers and strings and lists in py2.7

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: That means... `x` is not defined... Python basics, you have to initialize variables before you use them!

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592565/determine-if-variable-is-defined-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use python ternary operator. In your example, this might help you. You can extend the same further too.

```
#if X is None, do nothing
>>> x = ''
>>> x if x and x>0 else None
#if x is not None, print it
>>> x = 1
>>> x if x and x>0 else None
1
```

Dealing with string values

```
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> x if x and len(x)>0 else None
'hello'
>>> x = ''
>>> x if x and len(x)>0 else None
>>>
```

Comment: `x=''` does not mean `x` is `None`, but rather a `str` of length 0. Use `x = None` instead. And while this works, the code of OP would already work, if his `x` was really `None`, but from the comments you see that `x` is indeed not defined. With `x` undefined, your solution fails, too.

Comment: In this case, be careful with `if x`, because things other than `None` can evaluate to `False`.

Comment: Following up on @Tomothy32 - try your operator with `x=0`. What output do you expect?

Comment: @Tomothy32, I read your comment. Yes, X must be defined prior this condition check. I agree with if x, that will fail as you said but here we have another check which evaluates is X value is greater than 0. In such case, >>> x = 'str'
>>> x if x and len(x)>0 else None
'str'

Comment: @ChristianKönig Well... 0 isn't the best example because of the `x > 0` condition, but the point is clear.

Comment: @ChristianKönig, if x=0, yet the condition fail and else loop be in effective. Because, 0>0 is false.
>>> x = 0
>>> x if x and x>0 else None
>>>

Comment: @Ajay2588 But, for strings, your answer doesn't say `len(x) > 0`, it says `x > 0`. But I guess it's implied it's a number because of the `x > 0`. Still, it's never bad to be more careful; `if x is not None` is more explicit.

Comment: @ChristianKönig, you are right. However, in my reply to Tomothy, I have written that peace of code too. Let me add the same in my answer section too.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn’t have a specific function to test whether a variable is defined, since all variables are expected to have been defined before use, even if initially assigned the None object. Attempting to access a variable that hasn’t previously been defined raises a NameError exception (which you can handle with a try/except statement, as you can for any other Python exception).

```
try: x
except NameError: some_fallback_operation(  )
else: some_operation(x)
```

Reference :
[Testing if a Variable Is Defined](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch17s02.html)

Answer (score 0):

some code like:

```
if x and x > 0:
    pass
```