# How do I find the user's name in a form?

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord, discord.py, gspread

So I am currently working on a Discord.py bot and am trying to find if the user is already registered through the bot with GSpread. I've tried a few things like :

```
if findUser is None:
   print("User not found!")
if findUser:
   print("Found user!")
```

It worked when the user was found, but when I removed the username from the spreadsheet, it broke.

```
@bot.command()
async def finduser(message):
    user = (message.author.name+message.author.discriminator)
    print(user)
    findUser = sheet.find(user, in_column=3)

    if findUser:
        print("User found!")
    else:
        print("User not found!")
```

Anyways, if anyone could help me out, that would be awesome!

-ekalb2020

Comment: whats your error if you remove the name from the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Was fairly simple, just was misunderstanding how to use the statement!

```
@bot.command()
async def finduser(message): 
    user = (message.author.name+message.author.discriminator)
    print(user)
    
    try:
        sheet.find(user, in_column=3)
    except:
        print("User not found!")
    else:
        print("User found!")
```

Find more on the try statement here: [Determine if variable is defined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592565/determine-if-variable-is-defined-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

What about just changing the conditions? Since it worked on the first example, you could just use it in the second example

```py
@bot.command()
async def finduser(message):
    user = (message.author.name+message.author.discriminator)
    print(user)
    findUser = sheet.find(user, in_column=3)

    if findUser is None:
        print("User not found!")

    else:
        print("User found!")
```

Comment: I don't know haha. I'm incredibly confused now. All I really know is that I want to check if the user is found in the sheet and print a statement saying if they were or weren't. Your/my (idek anymore) fix doesn't work btw.